# What are these extra processes?

Tags: electron

In my Electron app, I have my main process and two renderer windows open.  Why does Task Manager show **8** "electron.exe" processes?  I would expect it to be 3.

Thanks.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2437) on Electron provides a start to understanding why so many processes show up on Task Manager.
Looks like it's due to [Chromium's multi-process architecture](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture).

Comment: Thanks, @Neil.  I understand that each renderer has its own process and Main has a process, but I don't understand why there are 8 in Task Manager.  1 main plus 2 renderers should mean only 3 processes.

Comment: Chromium's behind those extra ones. Taking an app I recently wrote as an example (only 1 Renderer). Task Manager shows *3* processes running when I launch it. Upon closer inspection through Process Hacker (installed as a Task Manager replacement) reveals 1 process having no CLI arguments (main), 1 process having `--type=renderer` as the argument while the third has `--type=gpu-process` (right-click, show properties on each process).  You can check all your processes to determine what each is for, but at the end of the day, the extra ones are because of the way Chromium manages things, imo.

Comment: it's probable that gpu acceleration opens an additional process for every window (It's not like that on 2.0.2 though). If you're interested turn it off by [`app.disableHardwareAcceleration()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appdisablehardwareacceleration) and see what happens. I think you'll get the expected 3-4 processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Extra processes are electron listeners.

A new process will spawn every time you add a listener to **ipcMain** or **ipcRenderer**.

**Example**:

```js
ipcRenderer.on("data", (e, data) => {
  console.log("this will spawn a process")
})
```

**More**:

- If you **start your app**:

  - [image]
- If you **add a listener**:

  - [image]
- If a **window is visible**, Windows joins them all in a group:

  - [image]

Just wondering if there's any way to specify a process id or something to join them together...